# Masking IP's with javascript

Tags: javascript, ip-address

I'm currently making a program to log onto some accounts that I created but after about 30 accounts a captcha appears, so what I was wondering was if I could mask the IP and bypass the captcha.

Not sure if this is possible in javascript, could anyone recommend a language to do this in?

**The Code:**

```
num = 0
function loop(){
num = num+1
console.log(num)
u = ''+num
p = ''

var data = {username:u,password:p};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'https://www.roblox.com/newlogin',
  data: data,
  error: function(data2){
$.get("http://www.roblox.com/my/account")
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'https://www.roblox.com/authentication/logout',
  data: data,
  success: function(data2){
loop()
}
});
  },
  success: function(data2){
$.get("http://www.roblox.com/my/account")
console.log(data)
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'https://www.roblox.com/authentication/logout',
  data: data,
  success: function(data2){
loop()
}
});
}
});
}
loop()
```

Comment: Contact the http://www.roblox.com and ask them to disable captcha for your account.

Comment: @zerkms Not really an option.

Comment: I think it is, just try. If it's not against law and their ToS they will do that for sure.

Comment: If they have an auth API, use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mask an IP with only Javascript. In fact, if you need a response back from the site, you can't really do it with any language because the response has to get routed back to your IP address.

Some things you can do:

1. Set up some proxies with multiple IP addresses and route your requests through the proxies.
2. Slow down your requests to a rate that doesn't trigger the captcha.
3. Get the right credentials from the site to make requests at the rate you are.
4. Use an API rather than a web page.